# Implement MariaDB/ColumnStore on Docker with volumes

Tags: mariadb, docker

I'm trying to implement MariaDB ColumnStore on Docker, as explained [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/mariadb/columnstore).

But I only see two options to store the data, either locally in the container or in S3. What I need is to have an external/persistent docker volume with the data.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is this on your own machine?  Or some Cloud service?  Isn't S3 persistent?

Comment: Is in my machine and on Azure

Comment: That is you want the code on your machine, but the data across the network?  Sounds risky.

Comment: No, data in my machine for development and on azure for production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 --name cont_mariadb 
-v vol_mariadb:/var/lib/mysql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-pwd mariadb/columnstore
```

Comment: Please mark your own answer as correct - it may help others in the future!